# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '300.00' to data type int

Tags: sql-server-2008

Is there a way to get rid of this error when using the following sql case when query?As some of the fields are varchar due to they way they were imported?

```
select * ,
case when [Month] = '200911' then netpay_nov09
 when [Month] = '200912' then netpay_dec09
 when [Month] = '201001' then netpay_jan10
end as m1
```

Comment: Are all those netpay_* columns varchar/integer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since those `varchar` columns seem to potentially contain REAL values, convert them to REAL explicitly and ROUND them, as follows:

```
select * ,
    case 
         when [Month] = '200911' then ROUND(CONVERT(REAL, netpay_nov09), 0)
         when [Month] = '200912' then ROUND(CONVERT(REAL, netpay_dec09), 0)
         when [Month] = '201001' then ROUND(CONVERT(REAL, netpay_jan10), 0)
    end as m1
....
```